# Preparing for Mathematics Olympiad

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, contest-math, self-learning

I am preparing for Mathematics Olympiad , can any one suggest me some books to prepare for olympiad ? The topics that usually come up involve:

- congruence modulo $n$,
- inequalities ,
- number system, elementary number theory, etc.

Please help me!

Thanks

Kushashwa

Comment: Please consider tagging this as soft-question

Comment: If it is off-topic, why shouldn't we take it as so? Never preamble your question with "do this." Whenever I see a question insisting it isn't off topic, it almost invariably is off-topic, so it is a bad thing to start with, if you are actually on-topic.

Comment: @chubakueno I think "reference request" is actual correct tag.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Oh, I actually didnn't know that tag. After reading the description, I also think it is more appropiate.

Comment: Spend some regular time doing old Olympiad problems - there are books and websites with solved problems. Don't look up the answer too soon. When you get to the answer, ask yourself - how did I find that way through in the end? What stopped me seeing it sooner? What were the clues I might have seen that this approach would work? Is there a way to improve that solution? Or if you had to look it up "how could I have spotted that myself? You will find that there are pretty regular questions on functional equations and geometry as well as the topics you mention.

Comment: If you had some Pre Regional Mathematics Olympiad question papers please send it to me.If you want to help me I can provide my E-Mail address to send those papers.I really need it.For any help thanks!!!

Comment: @Ayushakj - http://olympiads.hbcse.tifr.res.in/subjects/mathematics/previous-question-papers-and-solutions

This link, I hope, will help you in that. Good Luck!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'd recommend that you visit the [Art of Problem Solving](http://artofproblemsolving.com/articles)'s (AoPS) website: I've linked you to their "resource" page with articles you can download (they are freely accessible.) The website is a "hub" for very motivated students of mathematics, many of whom engage in competition math. The site hosts mathematics resources, curricula, on-line forums, and a ["bookstore"](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/store). So feel free to explore the vast site.

Given the topics you specifically mention, I'll link you to some pdf notes on *[Number Theory](http://artofproblemsolving.com/articles/files/SatoNT.pdf)*; it's about 40-some odd pages, covering the topics you mention, and more.  I'll also link you to a pdf entitled [*Olympiad Number Theory: an Abstract Perspective.*](http://artofproblemsolving.com/articles/files/MildorfNT.pdf) You'll find at least two (freely accessible) notes in pdf on inequalities available for downloading, at the linked page at the top. Here's one of those: [*Inequalities*](http://artofproblemsolving.com/articles/files/KedlayaInequalities.pdf).

Enjoy!

Comment: You're very welcome!

Comment: @amWhy: Good points for the OP. :+)

Answer (score 4):

Buy AoPS books starting from pre algebra and work your way to precalculus... Then just buy practice amc, aime, and usamo tests from the MAA website:

Also I recommend reading the book polynomials by Barbeau as well as Art and Craft of Problem Solving.

For a lighter read go through the Barron's E-Z series in each math subject before touching the AoPS volume. This will make your transition from learning topics to learning to problem solve a lot easier.

Comment: It's probably easier to find the tests online than buy them from the MAA.

Answer (score 3):

These following books are good:

- [Problem Solving Strategies](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387982191) by Arthur Engel
- [Mathematical Circles](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0821804308) by Dmitri Fomin et al
- [The USSR Olympiad Problem Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486277097) by D. O. Shklarsky et al
- Others books By [Titu Andreescu](https://www.amazon.com/Titu-Andreescu/e/B001IOH5N2) and [Isaak Yaglom](https://www.amazon.com/s?i=stripbooks&rh=p_27%3AI.+M.+Yaglom)

Comment: Could you please share the link to download these books.

Comment: @blue boy can I also send you my email? I am also interested in those books

Comment: @blue boy my email id is sohamchatterjee.rkm@gmail.com  please send me the books